# Attempt to reconnect to BLE once connection is lost in flutter_reactive_ble

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get my app to automatically attempt at reconnecting to a ble device if connection was lost. I am following the example provided in [here](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble) but cant find out a way. Is that even possible? Any recommendation will greatly help

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to share what you tried to do. Here on SO we help with problems related to your code, we don't provide ready answers, for ready answers you have google, thanks.

Comment: Please add some code of what you've tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.